# Sql query changed after magento update

Tags: collection, upgrade, magento1.9.2.4

I recently updated my Magento to 1.8.0.1 to 1.9.2.4, after that is some code which is not working the way it was working before. In one of my custom module(purchased module)
there was a collection filter like this-

```
$weekCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')->getCollection()
         ->addFieldToFilter('id',16)
         ->addFieldToFilter('week(created_time, 1)',$week);
```

it's sql query was

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `table_name` AS `main_table` WHERE (`id` = '16') AND (week(`created_time`, 1) = '13')
```

this query was working fine in older veriosn

after updating magento  the query for that code is

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `table_name` AS `main_table` WHERE (`id` = '16') AND (`week(created_time, 1)` = '13')
```

this is returning errror of  **Unknown column 'week(created_time, 1)' in 'where clause'**

What change should I make in `addFieldToFilter`  code to make the sql query same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code, that will work for you

```
$weekCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')->getCollection()
     ->addFieldToFilter('id',16);

$weekCollection->getSelect()->where("week(created_time, 1) = $week");
```

Comment: you are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Update your code:

```
$_week = week(created_time, 1);
$weekCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')->getCollection()
             ->addFieldToFilter('id',16)
             ->addFieldToFilter($_week,$week);
```

Comment: it returns fatal error Call to undefined function week()

Comment: I've updated my answer, try again

Comment: same error again

Comment: I've updated my answer, try again

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`` $weekCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('id',`16)
    ->getSelect()
    ->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("week(created_time, 1) = $week")); ``